# ArrayList Doesnt update contents over socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, debugging, arraylist

I have a typical multi threaded server and a client that connects over socket with the server and does some operation.

Client part:

```
try {
        mySocket=new Socket("localhost", 1234);


    ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());  
    ObjectInputStream  ois= new ObjectInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());


           try{
               while(true){

               //Here user is asked for input the protocol string  

                    if("one message".equals(protocol))                             
                       {   
                        oos.writeObject(protocol); 
                        oos.flush();

                        mylist=(ArrayList<MyClass>)ois.readObject();
                        System.out.println(mylist);
                       }


                    if("two message".equals(protocol))  
                        { 
                          //tell server to change few things    on the list                                               
                        }

}//end while        
        } //end inner try
                    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                        // ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            mySocket.close();

}//end outer try 
        catch (IOException e)
    {
        //message
    }
```

And Server Side:

```
public void run() {
try{

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());               
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());  

    String protocol;


  try{

  while(true)
    {            
        protocol= (String)ois.readObject();


    if ("one message".equals(protocol))
            {                                
             oos.writeObject(list); 
             oos.flush();

             System.out.println(list);
         }


     if ("two message".equals(protocol))

    {
      //change objects in the list          
    }



} //end while true

    } //end try
                catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex)
                {                        
                   // ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            socket.close();
}  
  catch (Exception ex)
            {                   
                //ex.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

The problematic part is here:

```
if ("one message".equals(protocol))
                {

                 oos.writeObject(list); //sends the wrong (?)
                 oos.flush();

                 System.out.println(list); //prints the correct
             }
```

Server from its side, seems to print the correct list every time user changes something. But then, clients receives and prints the 1st list, no matter how many changes the client makes. If Another thread comes and ask for the list it will take the latest list, if that thread or another makes more changes the server will still print the correct lists everytime from its side, but clients will always get back the wrong list, which is the list that existed when that client thread came in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ObjectOutputStream, if you ask it to send an object it has already sent, simply sends a reference to the previously sent object. This is what allows sending a complex graph of objects, with bidirectional references or cycles between objects.

If you want the stream to forget about what it has already sent, then you need to call the [`reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) method.

Comment: I love you, thanks it works apparently. Something else, it isn't need to use flash() once you used reset() ? It works for me with just reset() and not flash() fine, but what is the optimal technique?

Comment: If you need to flush(), then call flush(). If you need to reset(), then call reset(). They do different things, and the documentation doesn't say that reset() also flushes the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You're a victim of Object caching in the serialization streams. The first time you write an object a cached version of it is being created for that reference address. Then each time you write it (even though you change the contents) it is not writing it again because it says "I have already seem the object at this address".

The best way to fix this is to keep the socket streams outside the while loop but put the ObjectOutput and ObjectInput streams inside your while loop. This should solve your problem. Typically one set of these is design for one stable object graph.

Comment: thanks for input, ill keep it in mind for next time.